# Why still in public beta @ Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

Why are so many sites in Area 51 still on public beta, even if they have completed the beta phase?

Comment: showing some examples might help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), in which Robert explains that even after the initial 90 days sites won't graduate until they have enough high rep users, so that the site can still work with the non-beta reputation requirements. Basically that means that a site needs an excellent score in the "avid users" category.
2. A site won't graduate until Jin has finished its design. Since Jin can only do so much work at a time, there is currently a queue of sites which meet the graduation requirements, through which Jin is working one by one.

See also [this excellent answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/beta-progress-importance-of-reputation-and-voting/264#264) by Michael Mrozek on the Unix & Linux meta site.