# What's the time necessary for a proposal get deleted on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Some proposals have no activity for 1 or more months and stay on Area 51. Some examples:

- **[The Simpsons](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2786/the-simpsons) The only activity here is a comment stating that the proposal is a subset of another proposal, no real activity**
- [Persian Information Technology and Computer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) Maybe because it is on commit phase but see [No Artificial Intelligence in Area 51](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/) to figure out about the problem
- [Taxation and Accounting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1897/taxation-and-accounting)
- [FitNesse](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4737/fitnesse)
- [Magic & Sleight of Hand](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4172/magic-sleight-of-hand) I'm committed here but I can't help
- [Bartending and Alcoholic Beverages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4141/bartending-and-alcoholic-beverages)
- **[Debate Society](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3748/debate-society) This is a record! Someone could do something to generate activity artificially but this proposal is pretty dead. 6 months looking into Latest Activity**
- [CG - Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7287/cg-computer-graphics)
- [High Energy Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6633/high-energy-physics)
- [Soccer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6128/soccer) I could generate activity here but it didn't worth. It's clear that it lacks interest
- [Moderators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5648/moderators)
- [New York City](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8354/new-york-city)
- [Music Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8059/music-education)
- [Music History](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7686/music-history)
- [Embedded Linux](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13358/embedded-linux)
- [PUA Den](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13306/pua-den)
- [Blogging and Copywriting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10929/blogging-and-copywriting)
- [High School Academics Q&A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17930/high-school-academics-qa)
- [Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17115/science)
- [Open Social Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16633/open-social-learning)
- [Collecting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22148/collecting)
- [Song Lyrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21658/song-lyrics)
- **[The Practicing Musician](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21307/the-practicing-musician) Has absolutely NO activity!!!**
- [Путеводитель по жизни в России](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21208/)
- [Second Life](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20919/second-life)
- [Chefs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20615/chefs)
- [Business System Analyst - Banking, Financial Services, Insurance Domain](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20335/business-system-analyst-banking-financial-services-insurance-domain)
- [The X Window System](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20129/the-x-window-system)
- [Computer Architecture & Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19424/computer-architecture-organization)
- [Nursing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19231/nursing)
- [Electronics & Electrical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18854/electronics-electrical-engineering)
- [LET'S KNOW SOMETHING NEW..](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18685/lets-know-something-new)
- [Tabletop Game Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18588/tabletop-game-design)
- [Volunteering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23319/volunteering)
- [Exotic Pets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23196/exotic-pets)
- **[SAS Programming Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22964/sas-programming-language) Latest follower and question added or edit on Oct 21, latest comment posted on Nov 14. No votes casted. No activity for 2 months and no real activity since the creation. It overlaps Stack Overflow.**
- [Chinaexpat](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22951/chinaexpat)

EDIT: I let just the best examples and my list resurrected some proposals :)

Some of them have "just" the lack of activity problem, but most have other problems either.

Proponents have no activity on Area 51 for months on some proposals.

People think that just building it is enough for a proposal to get success. It's a hard work.

If the proposal is really important it would be healthy it start again to prove its viability. Of course it rarely or never will happen.

What counts as activity?

I missed something visible? Are there not visible activities?

Comment: I'm curious about the down-votes.

Comment: A couple guesses... 1) Examples are great, examples are fine, but **two pages** of examples is excessive. 2) the "field of dreams" comment was unnecessary and somewhat mean. (FWIW: Robert has [commented extensively on the A51 deletion strategy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A98786+area51+delete+inactive) before - the "1 month no activity" thing does not seem to have ever been a hard and fast rule for deletion, and the current A51 FAQ merely states that such proposals "**may** be deleted")

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks for guesses. Better now?  If a funny comment is reason to down-vote many more posts would be down-voted, probably half of yours that I read :) Most of questions listed on link provides barely touch the topic about deletion and none answers what I asked here. I'm not demanding any delete. I just ask about a doubt mine and provide an extensive list to help to point a review if needed. Anyway I think it's normal has a double standard about questions on a huge community, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73557/why-still-in-public-beta-area-51

Comment: the point of that link was that proposal deletion is a judgement call, with activity being just one factor. And yes, I do collect downvotes on many of my posts... It's natural.

Answer (score 7):

Proposals without activity prior to 2010-12-01 have been deleted, with few exceptions. Proposal activity includes added questions, comments, followers or committers, edits, and voting. Almost *all* the sites in your list contain such activity.

Comment: So latest activity is calculated wrongly? Let an useless comment is an ease way to keep abandoned proposals breathing through machines.

Comment: I shrink the list based on your answer.

Comment: @Robert: Can you update your answer to state about the possibility of  latest activity is miscalculated?

Comment: @bigown: I don't understand what you feel is being miscalculated. I told you exactly what counts as activity. It's the last date of Proposal Creation, Proposal Comment, Follow, Commit, Question Creation, Question Comment, Question Edit, Question Vote.

Comment: @Robert: See this example: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3748/debate-society Latest activity says 6 months (06-30-2010) but actual latest activity is 11-30-2010 (a follower) or later (I can't say when last vote was binded). As you stated in your original answer almost all the sites in my original huge list contain such activity. I did that list looking into LATEST ACTIVITY information on right bar, below the VIEWED information and the FOLLOWERS graph. In original list with ~150 proposals this information shows 1 month or more.

Comment: @bigown: I wonder if this shouldn't be a separate [bug]-report then...

Comment: @Shog9: Perhaps I post a bug report, but I'm confused yet.

Comment: @bigown: That's why you should post a bug report. You expect the system to work a certain way (latest activity to reflect any and all activity) but it appears to work a different way (latest activity reflects only edits or posts) - either that's considered a bug by the developers (and fixed in some fashion) or it's considered by-design (and marked accordingly for future reference). But regardless, it's outside the scope of *this* question.

Comment: @bigown: Ah, EUREKA! I understand what you are saying now. I didn't realize you were talking about the field labeled "Latest Activity" on the proposal screen. The screen display is showing different criteria (when last new question was posted). My database query is much more liberal in determining "latest activity" (pretty much when *anything* has been added, voted, or edited) to determine whether a proposal has been abandoned, or not. I guess there is an argument that they *should* be synced up because of the way the FAQ is written. Post it as a [feature-request].

Comment: @Robert: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74229/latest-activity-at-area-51-could-be-wrongly-calculated

Comment: I see that. @David's explanation is sound.