# Why is answers.onstartups.com stuck in beta stage?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why still in public beta @ Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73557/why-still-in-public-beta-area-51)

I have been using [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com) for over two years and the site's name still has 'beta' in it. Why?

Comment: I'm wondering if the question per day thing can be overlooked a bit where that site is concerned. It's definitely getting traffic and excels in all other areas. Maybe a formal design would help it along the way? (sort of a sink or swim proposition though)

Comment: This site is definitely not going to be closed unless entrepreneurship suddenly loses its appeal or something unexpected happens. See the [Area51 Stats on OnStartups](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business). Graduation is imminent, it's just a matter of the community continuing to grow to the point where there are more quality questions being asked per day. To help it grow, keep tweeting good questions to your followers and continue to make people aware of this great resource.